# Struts2 404 error - basic exercise

Tags: java, struts2, struts-config

i'm learning struts2 framework and i'm trying to make a first exercise (following a guide).

The exercise is a simple Hello World...

When I run on server my application, the page show me the error 404, The requested resource is not available.

I don't know why. I searched other questions about this problem, but they resolved, adding a missing library and something else, but doesn't work with me...

Applications of other users work and the Tomcat server redirect me corretly with a classic localhost:8080..

So how can I resolve my problem?

This is my code:
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>PrimoEsercizio</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

<filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"></constant>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getMessage" class="primoPackage.TutorialAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>          
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

TutorialAction.java class

package primoPackage;

```
public class TutorialAction {

        public String execute() {
            System.out.println("Ciao, ecco il primo execute");
            return "success";
        }
}
```

success.jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Reindirizzamento avvenuto con successo!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[libreries struts2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ksOd.png)

[image: libreries project proprieties]

[image]

[image]

Comment: just an of the topic question, do you have to learn Struts (job, school) or did you choose that framework yrself? Because it's old and bad.

Comment: I'm using struts2 because i'm working in a company that required this framework...

Comment: ok then, ignore me.

Comment: @JackFlamp Struts2 isn't old and isn't bad.

Comment: @AlessandroSiverino xwork jar is for version 2.3.34. You don't need it in 2.5.13. Please follow official tutorial - https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/.

Comment: @JackFlamp it might be old but not bad.

Comment: fair enough, I didn't mean to hijack this question with personal opinions. Others, like spring mvc are just so much nicer to work with..

Comment: @JackFlamp, I'm interested how to make Struts better. Could you please post me your opinions about why Spring MVC here or at https://lists.apache.org/list.html?user@struts.apache.org?